How to wrap a text inside a macOS popover
I have the following view - https://github.com/p0deje/Maccy/blob/master/Maccy/Views/PreviewItemView.swift
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
      // some code
      Text(item.text)
        .controlSize(.regular)
        .lineLimit(100)
      // more code
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: 800)

The text wraps finely for multiline content but fails to wrap for single-line strings. Is there any way to properly wrap the text so it spawns on multiple lines?
I've tried multiple combinations of lineLimit, fixedSize, geometry reader, but every solution ended up breaking in some other weird way.
What I am trying to achieve:

What I get instead:


I guess this is only a preview issue, since preview does not really care with high priority for your frame with the maxWidth parameter.
So you better try
.frame(width: 800)

at the Preview part instead, it will work.
#Preview {
ContentView()
    .frame(width: 800)
}

If it happens on the popover when running the app, you should also consider giving it a fixed width.

This is an issue in production, not preview. Adding a fixed width works, but I would like the width to shrink whenever the text is short.
